# Can someone identify this uniform?

Tags: identification, uniform

[image]
This was my great great grandfather. He arrived at the port of Tampico in Mexico in the second half of the 19th century. Identifying his military uniform would help me a lot knowing where I come from.

EDIT (from comment)

The uniform looks kinda blue or grey, the mustache blonde, the cap shows a more prominent number 12.

Comment: sorry - but there just isn't enough detail in that photograph to make a reasonable identification.

Comment: It looks like this may be a crop of a larger image. Do you perhaps have the larger image which may provide more of the uniforms?

Comment: That's all I got, took another picture but the only change is the quality, uniform looks kinda blue or grey, mustache blonde, cap show a more prominent number 12, sorry, is all that could be saved from the original portrait,  or so I was told :/, I have failed fellow history enthusiasts.

Comment: Union Army seems plausible, but I doubt you're going to get much more info than that without a better photo. (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/War_of_the_Rebellion_Atlas_Plate_172.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  another guy told me that his money was on US Navy,  1850-1860's

Answer (score 1):

The 12 on the cap gives us something to go on, though there were several units designated 12th in the civil war.  An image of [Colonel Fletcher Webster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher_Webster) , of the [12th Regiment Massachusetts Volunteer Infantry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12th_Regiment_Massachusetts_Volunteer_Infantry), shows characteristics similar to your image.

[image]